# Remove unwanted elements from arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table `scraped_listings` and a table `scraped_categories`. The column `scraped_listings.categories` is an integer[] array containing ids of rows in `scraped_categories`.

Somehow (probably through a mistake I don't remember making), some scraped_listings rows have ids in categories that do NOT belong to a category row (those rows have been deleted, I suspect).

I have the following query, which gives me the rows affected:

```
SELECT * FROM scraped_listings a
JOIN (
  SELECT array_agg(id) AS ids
  FROM scraped_categories
  ) b ON NOT a.categories <@ b.ids;
```

What I'd like to do now is to remove the ids which are not valid from `categories` for the rows found by this query - if an item in the array is not a valid scraped_category id, it should be dropped.

How might I do this?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that by "array" you mean a comma-delimited list of integers?

Comment: @Dan: Yes; I'll update the question to make that more explicit.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize PostgreSQL supports actual arrays as columns.

Comment: As *always*: Table definitions and Postgres version please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres **9.2 or earlier**:

```
UPDATE scraped_listings s
SET   categories = up.categories
FROM (
    SELECT a.pkey, array_agg(a.id) AS categories
    FROM  (
        SELECT pkey, unnest (categories) AS id
        FROM   scraped_listings
        ) a
    JOIN scraped_categories s USING (id) -- eliminates unwanted ids
    ) up
WHERE s.pkey = up.pkey
```

`pkey`being the undisclosed primary key column of `scraped_listings`.

In Postgres **9.3** you would use `LATERAL` for the correlated `unnest()`:

```
UPDATE scraped_listings s
SET   categories = up.categories
FROM (
    SELECT a.pkey, array_agg(a.id) AS categories
    FROM  (
        SELECT pkey, c_id AS id
        FROM   scraped_listings l, unnest(l.categories) c_id  -- implicit LATERAL
        ) a
    JOIN scraped_categories s USING (id) -- eliminates unwanted ids
    ) up
WHERE s.pkey = up.pkey
```

Or you install the additional module [**`intarray`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html), that ships additional operators for `int[]`, like:

```
int[] - int     int[]   remove entries matching right argument from array
```