# Postgres eliminate multiple rows with the same ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table with an ID and some space-delimited segments:

```
                     id        |   segments
-------------------------------+-----------------------
 2A3A3362051D43-6000014002B3C4 | 73024 73025
 2A399D20051D96-4000010002782A | 96878 92779 73024 73025
 2A3747D3051DE0-40000100032E40 | 139313
 29C1D823851DDF-400001200FD641 | 139313
```

The problem is that some of these ID's are repeated:

```
                 id            |         segments
-------------------------------+--------------------------
 27295CD0851AB2-400000E01059BF | 139313
 27295CD0851AB2-400000E01059BF | 139313
 27295CD0851AB2-400000E01059BF | 139313 92779 73024 73025
 27295CD0851AB2-400000E01059BF | 139313
 27295CD0851AB2-400000E01059BF | 139313
```

The issue is how to delete the unnecessary rows and keep only one row per ID, while also retaining all of the segments (they are random, and I must keep each one) segments are stored as text, so simple string concatenation will work.

Comment: Your table definition (`\d tbl` in psql)? Your version of Postgres? Is it ok to merge arrays (I presume) in `segments`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really bad data format.  You should have a separate table with one row per id and per segment.  Storing lists of things in a separate list is not taking good advantage of relational databases.  Storing numeric values as strings is even worse.

That said, sometimes you are stuck with data in a particular format.  You can unnest the string, get distinct values, and re-aggregate to do what you want:

```
select id, string_agg(segment, ' ')
from (select distinct id, unnest(string_to_array(segments, ' ')) as segment
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: I agree that it is a bad format, but it's what I have to work with.

Your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a simple text column:

```
SELECT id, string_agg(DISTINCT seg) AS segments
FROM   tbl
     , unnest(string_to_array(segments, ' ')) seg
GROUP  BY 1;
```

In pg 9.3 rather use a `LATERAL` join than calling a set-returning function in the `SELECT` list. Related answer with more details:

- [Remove unwanted elements from arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520472/remove-unwanted-elements-from-arrays/19522664#19522664)

Consider [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table layout.